# Windows mobile UI: Is a messagebox appropriate to display information?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, mobile

I have a list of items in a listview and when the user double-clicks an item, I display a messagebox with the contact's name and address.

My boss doesn;t like it because he thinks this violate some UI design principle for Windows Mobile devices. I can't find anything that prohibits this. He is thinking that it has something to do with the device not being able to go into power-saving mode when a message-box is displayed.

Is he right? Can you suggest an alternative (he doesn;t have an alternative except he doesn;t like what i have)

C#, Windows Mobile 6.0, WinForms

Answer (score 1):

Windows Mobile 6 uses MessageBox all the time. It is probably better than rolling your own solution because you'll automatically benefit from updates in WM6.5 which a custom solution wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

The device has no problem going into power-saving mode while a message box is displayed.  Other options available to you include using a tabbed view and switching to another tab to display details, or creating and displaying a new form to display details.